# straight line and convex function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, convex-analysis

exercise:

For the purposes of this exercise we shall call a line that cuts a curve $y=f(x)$ a secant line. A secant line meets the curve and crosses it; it contains points $\left(x_{1}, y_{1}\right)$ and $\left(x_{2}, y_{2}\right)$, such that $y_{1}<f\left(x_{1}\right)$ and $y_{2}>f\left(x_{2}\right)$. Note that this is slightly different from the common usage, which requires a secant to meet the curve in two points, an assumption not made here.
Let $f$ be strictly convex in the whole real line. Show that a secant line that is parallel to some chord of the curve $y=f(x)$ cuts the curve in two points.

My effort:

[image]

considering convexity inequalities and the condition of the task we have
$$\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}<\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}<\frac{f(b)-f(x)}{b-x}$$
$$\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}<\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}=\frac{y-y_1}{x-x_1}<\frac{f(b)-f(x)}{b-x}$$ for every three points $a$, $x$ and $b$ in the
interval of definition, such that $a < x < b$

then I tried write an equation including straight line and the convex function $f(x)$ but couldn't proceed.
(I know the theorem which says a straight line intersects the graph
of strictly convex function in at most two points. Probably applicable here)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is not true. If you take $f$ to be a linear function, for example, then every chord is parallel (and indeed contained) in this line, but not every "secant" line is parallel to this line. You can get strictly convex counterexamples with hyperbolas too. Where did you get this question? I have no idea what to do to fix it.

Comment: @Theo Bendit -- Can you point out a concrete strictly convex counterexample? If a straight line touches the graph of a strictly convex function at some point, and then does not touch it at all any more, then by definition it is a support line of the graph, but then it is not a "secant line" according to the definition given in the original question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for replies. this is the exercise number 11 from the book "fundamental mathematical analysis" by Robert Magnus p-182

Comment: @uniquesolution Take the positive branch of [the hyperbola defined by $y(y - x) = 1$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x+%2B+%5Csqrt%28x%5E2+%2B+4%29%29%2F2). All of the chords will have strictly positive slope, but certain "secants" will have negative slope.

Comment: @TheoBendit -- The exercise explicitly assumes that the given secant line is parallel to some chord. Why do you care about certain secant lines that have negative slopes? IMHO the assertion is true, and my first comment essentially contains the proof.

Comment: @uniquesolution Whoops, I misread the question. I thought that we were supposed to prove that these "secants" (lines going through two points, one in and one out of the epigraph) were parallel to chords.

Comment: @uniquesolution if I understood your first comment correctly. proof should be by contradiction.  But I have never heard about support line to the graph, it is something as tangent line???

Comment: @emilagazade  -- yes, in the plane, a support line to a graph of a strictly convex function is just a tangent line. Yes, the proof is by contradiction: if our "secant line" does not touch the graph at a second point, then by continuity of the graph, it must lie in one of the two half spaces determined by the line, which renders the line a tangent line. This gives a contradiction to the fact that a secant line crosses the graph.

Comment: @uniquesolution so simple, so logic, nice thanks a lot